# Using jq to convert JSON {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"} into CSV: v1,v2

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I have a JSON file `in.txt` with lines like `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}` and I want to create from it a CSV file `out.txt` with lines `v1,v2`. The JSON file may contain more than 10 key/value pairs, so I prefer a solution that doesn't require specifying each key in the input command.

So far I found this command:

`jq -r '[.[]] | @csv' in.txt  > out.txt`

which produces output file with lines: `"v1","v2"`. How can I get rid of double quotes?

**update:** I can remove double quotes using `sed` as following, but I'm still interested to find a solution using jq:

`jq -r '[.[]] | @csv' in.txt | sed -e 's/\"//g' > out.txt`

Comment: Given a proper CSV parser, `"v1","v2"` and `v1,v2` are equivalent. Why do you care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the input data does not contain a `,` you can use `join(",")`.

Let's say you have this input file:

```
{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
{"k1":"v3","k2":"v4"}
{"k1":"v5","k2":"v6"}
```

You can use `join` like this:

```
jq -r 'values|join(",")' input.file
```

Output:

```
v1,v2
v3,v4
v5,v6
```

Comment: It doesn't work. But probably because originally I wrote in question `{"k1","v1","k2","v2"}` while in fact it's `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}`. Sorry for that

Comment: k. that's important to know. moment

Comment: Thank you! This works. Yes, I'm sure there are no `,` inside values